# d3.pie() returning 1/4 of a circle when creating a donut chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I'm trying to create  a donut chart with React and d3.js. I've been looking over the doc's on pies and charts here https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/v1.3.7/README.md#pie_startAngle. I'm struggling to figure out where I'm making my mistake. I have an array of objects and I'm getting the pie values using

```
  const createPie = d3
    .pie()
    .value(function(d) {return d.cases})
```

This returns an array with [image]

but when ever I try to use that data in an arc generator it only generates the arcs to a quarter of the circle. The following code is used to generate the quarter of an arc

```
  useEffect(
    () => {
      const data = createPie(pieData);
      console.log('data',data)
      let arcs = data.map( item => {
        let createTry = d3.arc()
          .innerRadius(300)
          .outerRadius(400)
          .startAngle(item.startAngle )
          .endAngle(item.endAngle);

          return createTry(item);
        
      });
      setArcs(arcs);
    }, [pieData]
  )
```

Finally I try to map the path generated onto an svg. I believe the problem stems from the d3.pie()

```
<div>
  <svg height={400} width={400}>    
    {arcs && arcs.map( arc => {
      return(
        <path d={arc}/>
      )
    })}
  </svg>
</div>
```

Any help or a point to a place in the docs that might help me understand my mistakes would be greatly appreciated. Thanks. Also here is a working example of the issue I'm having https://codesandbox.io/s/react-d3js-example-f4ylk?file=/src/components/Chart.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width and height of the SVG are 400, and the radius of your pie is 400 too. So only a quarter of the pie is visible.

If you increase the size of the SVG to 800 (radius x 2), and add a g element to contain your pie, which is translated to the centre of the SVG, then it will show.

For example, update your code to include:

```
return (
    <div>
      <svg height={800} width={800}><g transform="translate(400,400)">
        {arcs &&
          arcs.map(arc => {
            return <path d={arc} />;
          })}
      </g></svg>
    </div>
  );
```